# Mimicking Default Kubernetes CLI Output with GoLang Templates

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, go-templates

I want to customize the output of:

```shell
kubectl get pod . . .
```

with `--output=go-template` instead of `--output=yaml` or `--output=json`.

My purpose is to get additional values (e.g., container ports) in addition to the default columns (e.g., NAME, READY, STATUS, etc..,.) with one `get` command:

```shell
kubectl get pods --output=go-template --template=$GO_TEMPLATE

#=>

NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     CONTAINER PORTS   . . .
. . .          . . .   . . .     . . .      . . .   . . .             . . .
client-qfr4s   1/1     Running   0          14d     80,443            . . .
. . .          . . .   . . .     . . .      . . .   . . .             . . .
```

What is `$GO_TEMPLATE`?

Answer (score 6):

You can add custom columns to the output of the `get` command with the `--output=custom-columns` flag:

```shell
kubectl get pods \
--output=custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,RESTARTS:.status.containerStatuses[].restartCount,CONATAINER_NAME:.spec.containers[*].name,PORT:.spec.containers[*].ports[*],READY:.status.containerStatuses[*].ready'

#=>

NAME                         STATUS    RESTARTS   CONATAINER_NAME   PORT                                            READY
nginx-6bc98f4797-7kv6m       Pending   0          busy,nginx        map[containerPort:8000 protocol:TCP]            false,true
nginx-6bc98f4797-zv4sp       Pending   0          busy,nginx        map[containerPort:8000 protocol:TCP]            false,true
php-apache-5986bb6b9-gllq8   Running   5          php-apache        map[containerPort:80 protocol:TCP]              true
```

You can find more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `get`, you can use `describe` to get the complete status:

```shell
kubectl describe $K8S_POD_NAME

#=>

Name:         $K8S_POD_NAME
. . .
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
. . .
```